# Moved standard C header files like stdio.h around, broke the installation

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I was trying to fix issues with my clang installation for emscripten, for which I (foolishly) moved around certain C header files like `stdio.h`.
I reinstalled `gcc` and `libc6`, but it didn't fix the problem, so I can't even compile hello world programs like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
   printf("hello world\n"); 
   return 0;
}
```

This gives me the error

```
In file included from hello.c:1:0: /usr/include/stdio.h:20:3: error:
#error "Never include <bits/stdio.h> directly; use <stdio.h> instead."
#error "Never include <bits/stdio.h> directly; use <stdio.h> instead." 
hello.c: In function ‘main’:

hello.c:4:1: warning:
implicit declaration of function ‘printf’
[-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  printf("hello world\n");

hello.c:4:1: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in
function ‘printf’ 
hello.c:4:1: note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a
declaration of ‘printf’
```

Comment: Try to delete all the headers you moved, so only the ones inside gcc are left. It might work

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?